# All Lodash Functions "Not A Function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, lodash

I have lodash as part of my sails project.
It already existed as part of sails.
I have required it in my controller at the top of the file as such..

```
const lodash = require('lodash');
```

But no matter what I do, even though autocomplete suggests the function, anything done with them takes the whole app down and produces the "... is not a function" error. It is required fine and sails lifts.
I've tried testing with even simple things such as

```
lodash.foreach([1,2,3], function(a){
    sails.log.debug(a);
});
```

...and that produces the exact same error.

Comment: [The function is called `forEach`, not `foreach`.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelt foreach.

It's `forEach` like [this](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach):

```
_.forEach([1, 2], function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
// => Logs `1` then `2`.

_.forEach({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key);
});
// => Logs 'a' then 'b' (iteration order is not guaranteed).
```